# What are the side effects of using structs to group constants

Tags: go, memory, struct, constants

I know we can't use struct as constant in Go.
But I would like to group my constant for cleaner code, instead having many constant with some prefix, so I am doing this:

```
var SomeStatus = struct {
  Active   int
  Inactive int
  Others   int
}{
  Active: 1,
  Inactive: 2,
  Others: 3
}

// usage example
status = Status.Active

// example with some prefix
const StatusActive = 1
const StatusInactive = 2
const StatusOthers = 3
const OtherConstantVariable = 1
...
```

If it doesn't matter, the value of the variable can be rewritten.
What is the other side effect of this trick?

Comment: There's a slight performance impact because it's allocated memory instead of a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the other side effect of this trick?

The ones I can think of. There may be others:

- It's less efficient, as variables allocate runtime memory.
- Any values that could be pre-computed at compile time due to a constant, will now be calculated at runtime.
- For exported symbols, it opens you up to modification at runtime by anyone who imports your package.
- It's not idiomatic, so will potentially confuse anyone who sees your code.
- The flexibility that comes from untyped constants is lost.